# Breeding animal problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been trying to breed pigs, sheep, cows, and chickens, but I can only feed the cows, meaning I can only breed them and not the other animals. This is very annoying and I was wondering if anyone knew why this is happening

Comment: I ment problems

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding .

I suspect that you may not be using the correct breeding foods.
Of note is the following:

`Pigs require carrots Sheep require wheat Cows require wheat Chickens require seeds`

You also need two (at least) of the animal and they must have access to each other and you must wait 5 minutes between breedings.